# Android application install/uninstall event

Tags: android, installation, uninstallation

There is an application and it needs system reboot after installation. I registrered boot receiver and write info to system log. And activity checks for this line. It works well, but there is one problem...

When user uninstall and install this app in one session(I mean user doesn't reboot phone) system log still has line "Phone restarted" and application runs with errors.

As I know I can't check uninstallation event on my app cause receiver stops before the application going to uninstall. So my question is could I check for my app installation? or maybe uninstallation any other way?

Thanks!

Comment: You have bigger problems. Your "boot receiver" will not work until the user runs one of your activities, starting with Android 3.1. You need to rewrite your app to not require "reboot after installation" to run successfully.

Comment: @CommonsWare, thanks. Yeah, I've only tested it on 2.x versions for now. I'll rewrite the function to check reboot with anouther. But this app doesn't work without system restart so I still need some issue...

Comment: "But this app doesn't work without sustem restart" -- that's a bug in your app that you need to fix. Not every user is going to listen to you and reboot their phone, anyway.

Comment: Well, that's the user right, he could remove the app) It needs connectiion to system service. Anyway, I've just find a solution by checking AGAIN!!! system log for line "Finished uninstalling pkg ..." provided by UninstallAppProgress

Comment: Your approach will not work on Android 4.1 and above, as you can no longer read log messages other than the ones you write yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe someone will be interested. I found the code that allows me to checked system reboot after installation/update:

```
public static boolean phone_rebooted(Context ctx) {
        ApplicationInfo appInfo = ctx.getApplicationInfo();
        String appFile = appInfo.sourceDir;
        long installed = new File(appFile).lastModified();

        long boot_time = System.currentTimeMillis() - SystemClock.elapsedRealtime();
        if(boot_time < installed) {
           return false;
        } else {
           return true;
        }
    }
```